# I Installed Server.app on Yosemite to enable caching, but see many server processes in Task Manager (_xcsbuild and _devicemgr and _calendar processes)

Tags: server.app, macos

_xcsbuild and _devicemgr and _calendar processes seem to be the bulk.

None of them are using significant rescues but there are dozens.

How do I identify the launcctl jobs and turn them off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stop the _xcsbuild "session" by running `sudo xcrun xcscontrol --shutdown`. This will also stop it from starting at launch.

Although it's probably a better idea to use xcscontrol, the individual launchctl tasks are:

- `com.apple.xcsd.plist`
- `com.apple.xcscouch.plist`
- `com.apple.xcsredis.plist`
- `com.apple.xcscontrol.plist`

You can also delete all the remaining data by running `sudo xcrun xcscontrol --reset`.

I'm still looking myself for _devicemgr and _calendar, but just this one is enough to let you shut down/reboot without the warning.